# How to Integrate third party library instances with structure Map

Tags: c#, structuremap

Has anyone tried to manage their third party instances with structure Map ?

For the longest time, my approach to managing third party library has been to write  a wrapper around the library api.

What I am faced is with a dilemma of how to leverage dependency injection benefit of structure maps while I still get to preserve my wrappers around third party libraries.

For example if I have a LibraryClass and I have my class WrapperClass. My wrapper constructor will look like the following.

```
    class WrapperClass : IWrapperClass{
       var instance;
       public WrapperClass(){
            instance = new LibrayClass();
       }
    }
```

The problem with this is that wherever I use this in my code, I can't mock this object because structure map needs to have access to the LibraryClass type in order to load WrapperClass.

What do people do for this ? Should I just expose the LibraryClass type to the structure map and hope in turn that it will just load through structure Map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have needed to inject a third party dependency, I put a wrapper around it with an interface. Instead of exposing the object as Instance, I try to expose function of the underlying object on the wrapper. For example, given AmazonS3, the wrapper class might look something like

```
class FileStorage : IFileStorage
{
    private AmazonS3 _amazon;
    public FileStorage(AmazonS3 amazon) { _amazon = amazon }
    void StoreFile(string file, string key)
    {
            _amazon.StoreFile(file, key);
    }
}
```

You can then inject IFileStorage into your class and because it is an interface you can mock that class for testing.

And you register the third library class type in your structure map configuration.

Comment: Won't Structure map complain that the AmazonS3 is not registered in structure map object factory ?

Comment: You have a couple options for that depending on your needed. 
1. Register AmazonS3 into structuremap
2. Setup IFileStorage as For<IFileStorage>().Use<FileStorage>().ctor<AmazonS3>().Is(new AmazonS3)
3. Just new up AmazonS3 in the constructor and remove it from the parameter list
For number 2, I can't remember if that does a singleton for the constructor or not, something to look into if you go that route

Comment: ok that's what I was asking, so you do expose the third party library type to the structure map.

Comment: Sorry, just updated by comment, i kept hitting the enter key instead of the shift + enter key.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, there is just no way around encapsulating the the third library type in the wrapper. I'll have to accept that exposure to leverage  the benefits of structure map.